# Touchpad random jumps and gestures - Acer V3-371

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I'm having some trouble with touchpad on Ubuntu 15.10. Always sooner or later (sometimes 30s, somtimes a few minutes) while using touchpad the cursor starts randomly jumping here and there (kinda like smartphone with wet screen). It doesn't look like hardware issue because it works well on Windows and simple system restart or switching off and on touchpad using keyboard shortcut fixes the problem for next few minutes.

1. What can I do to fix it?
2. How can I help you diagnose the issue?

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so please use simple words and copy-paste ready commands if it's possible. Thank you in advance for any help.

@edit: same goes for ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10. I bet it's a hardware problem

Comment: I guess you're using a Synaptics touchpad, so take a look and read this doc to determine wether your touchpad is this kind of and on how to install and configure it: [https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad) Welcome to the Linux world, the "place" where you're gonna learn how to read.

Comment: `egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices` does not display anything so I'm guessing that It's not synaptics touchpad. Even cat /proc/bus/input/devices doesn't print anything with touchpad in name. Maybe it's this one https://nopaste.me/view/32e17853

Comment: Searching a bit I found that, maybe it could help you. Can't figure what's happening, Not a common issue.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185329

Comment: After all that time I'm pretty sure that it's a hardware problem